# HTML Code index.html design does not fit to mobile view for Phonegap android application?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm new to Phonegap and making an app but my index.html and other html file does not fit to mobile view as android application. How to set all these webpages to fit to mobile screen to look like as an mobile application.

Below is my sample code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <div id="container" style="width:500px">

 <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
 <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>

 <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
 <b>Menu</b><br>
 HTML<br>
 CSS<br>
 JavaScript</div>

 <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
 Content goes here</div>



 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thinks your are missing viewport.

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
</head>
```

**user-scalable** - Controls whether the user can "pinch-to-zoom".

**width** - the width of the viewport.

**More Info :** [referencelink1](http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html), [referencelink2](http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2012/12/using-meta-viewport/)

Comment: Can u please send me one complete sample code for phongap for android for review as I'm new to this technology. Thanks

Comment: @Zohaib ok just give your mailID i'll send

Comment: @Zohaib check your mail zohaib

Comment: everyrhing is fine now... but when i launch my phonegap app, a black screen appears for long 6-8 seconds and then index page start.How to remove that black screen. Many people have asked this question online but there is no specific and right answer to this issue . Can you help me in this.

Comment: @Zohaib +1 If your testing it in emulator sure it'll come.check it in mobile and make sure in java main activity you redirecting only likethis public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
 }

Comment: everything is same as you written but i'm testing it on emulator. May be this is the reason. Thanks for the help. Your are very co-operative.. :):)

Comment: need your help regarding mobile web application...how to contact or chat to you?

Comment: open your gmail chat and ping me zohaib

Answer (score 0):

Not completly familar with Phonegap, but I'm assuming the viewport metatag is still required for the webview to snap to the device-width.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, min-width=device-width, initial-scale=1,  maximun-scale=1, user-scalability=0">
```